# Not able to lookup Remote EJB in JBoss 7.x

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

I am trying to connect to a Remote EJB that is deployed in a JBoss 7 Server. I tried to figure out what the JNDI name is by looking at the JNDI dump that I got from the JBoss CLI.
No matter what I try I cannot lookup the EJB.

I think that the jndi name should be: java:global/XNet/api/ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote

Here is the client that I am using:

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;

import com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote;
import com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.util.Properties;
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws NamingException
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );


        //ReceivingAPI ejbRemote = DomainHelper.getHQApi(com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI.class);
        ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote ejbRemote = App.lookupRemoteStatelessCalculator();

        ejbRemote.getOpenRcvdocForSite(null, 7);
    }

//    private static ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote lookupRemoteStatelessReceiving() throws NamingException {
//        
//    }
//    
    private static ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote lookupRemoteStatelessCalculator() throws NamingException {
        final Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://someserver.xmx.com:1199");
        // username
        jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "mycompany1");
        // password
        jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "<removed>");
        //final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);


        jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

        InitialContext context = new InitialContext( jndiProperties );
        // The app name is the application name of the deployed EJBs. This is typically the ear name
        // without the .ear suffix. However, the application name could be overridden in the application.xml of the
        // EJB deployment on the server.
        // Since we haven't deployed the application as a .ear, the app name for us will be an empty string
        final String appName = "XNet";
        // This is the module name of the deployed EJBs on the server. This is typically the jar name of the
        // EJB deployment, without the .jar suffix, but can be overridden via the ejb-jar.xml
        // In this example, we have deployed the EJBs in a jboss-as-ejb-remote-app.jar, so the module name is
        // jboss-as-ejb-remote-app
        final String moduleName = "api";
        // AS7 allows each deployment to have an (optional) distinct name. We haven't specified a distinct name for
        // our EJB deployment, so this is an empty string
        final String distinctName = "hq";
        // The EJB name which by default is the simple class name of the bean implementation class
        final String beanName = com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI.class.getSimpleName();
        // the remote view fully qualified class name
        final String viewClassName = ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote.class.getName();
        // let's do the lookup

        try {
            ReceivingAPI test1 = (ReceivingAPI)context.lookup("java:global/XNet/api/" + beanName + "_EJB!" + viewClassName);
            System.out.println("Test1 = " + test1.getClass().getName());
        } catch(Throwable t) {
          System.out.println(t);  
        }

        try {
            ReceivingAPI test = (ReceivingAPI)context.lookup("java:global/XNet/api/hq/" + beanName + "_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote");
            System.out.println("Test = " + test.getClass().getName());
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }

        try {
            ReceivingAPI test = (ReceivingAPI)context.lookup("ejb:XNet/api/hq/" + beanName + "_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote");
            System.out.println("Test = " + test.getClass().getName());
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
        return (ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote) context.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "_EJB!" + viewClassName);
    }

}
```

The output from the run of the previous java class:

```
Hello World!
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: global/XNet/api/ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.global.XNet.api."ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote"
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: global/XNet/api/hq/ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.global.XNet.api.hq."ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote"
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ejb:XNet/api/hq/ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.ejb:XNet.api.hq."ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote"
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ejb:XNet/api/hq/ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.ejb:XNet.api.hq."ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote"
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:127)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Here is the dump of the JNDI CLI Command:

```
[jboss1@hmudev01 bin]$ ./jboss-cli.sh --connect controller=localhost:10099
[standalone@localhost:10099 /] /subsystem=naming:jndi-view
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "java: contexts" => {
            "java:global" => {
                "XNet" => {
                    "class-name" => "javax.naming.Context",
                    "children" => {
                        "api" => {
                            "class-name" => "javax.naming.Context",
                            "children" => {
                                "ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBLocal" => {
                                    "class-name" => "com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBLocal$$$view46",
                                    "value" => "Proxy for view class: com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBLocal of EJB: ReceivingAPI_EJB"
                                },
                                "ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote" => {
                                    "class-name" => "com.sun.proxy.$Proxy272",
                                    "value" => "Proxy for remote EJB StatelessEJBLocator{appName='XNet', moduleName='api', distinctName='hq', beanName='ReceivingAPI_EJB', view='interface com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote'}"
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ...
    }
}
[standalone@localhost:10099 /]
```

Any my maven deps are as follows:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.receiving</groupId>
        <artifactId>xnet-domain-receiving-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-naming</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.marshalling</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-marshalling-river</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossall-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: For a remote lookup i think you can do away with anything `global` related as it'll be `ejb:` that you're after. Having said that, i think your lookup strings are a bit funky. It should be something like `ejb:<app_name>/<bean_name>!<bean_interface>`. This will change slightly if you're deployed in an `.ear`

Comment: So in your case, I think (assuming RNet is the name of your .jar) the String you're after is `ejb:RNet/ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBLocal` (note the lack of java:ejb). It looks like you're pushing in some non-standard ports into your jndi setup as well, assuming that's intentional. If that doesn't work, might want to look at jndiProps next.

Comment: Rhys you were mostly right but it gave the ability to figure out what I needed to do.  I will post it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comment above Rhys was right about the jndi string looking "funky".  I tried everything I thought.  Here is what worked for my situation.

The JNDI URL needs to look like this:

```
XNet/api/ReceivingAPI_EJB!com.mycompany.receiving.api.ReceivingAPI_EJBRemote
```

I also had to add add a dependency to the others shown in the question:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```